# What's this called? $f^{*}(C)$

Tags: functions

$f^{*}(C)=\{x\in R$ | $f(x) \in C\}$ according to my professor. What does this function mean? and\or what is this function called?

Comment: I think what you might have meant to write was $f^{-1}(C)$, called the pre-image of $C$ under $f$.

Comment: is that different than the inverse?

Comment: It's usually written $f^{-1}$, as in $f^{-1}(C) = \{x\in R\mid f(x)\in C\}$. Are you sure about that notation? The set is called the inverse image, or the preimage, of C under $f$. $f^{-1}$ is called the "$f$ inverse", and it is a partial function only if $f$ is 1-1. In any case it's a perfectly good *relation*.

Comment: maybe it's ment that $f^{*}\left(C\right):=\left\{f\left(x\right) | x\in C\right\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ instead?

Comment: Does your professor have good handwriting?

Comment: @Max Perhaps - that makes more sense, notationally. Then $f^*$ is the induced map taking subsets of the domain to subsets of the range.

Comment: yes, he even typed it up multiple  times this way.

Comment: Hmm you'd be hard-pressed to find a similar definition of $f^*$, whereas $f^{-1}$ is standard.

Comment: after your edit i think what you are looking for is the preimage of a function. (the set of solutions $x$ of $f\left(x\right)\in C$) which is closely related to the inverse of a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commenters have noted, the more common notation for this is $f^{-1}(C)$, which is denoted the *pre-image* or *inverse image*.   If $f$ maps elements of a set $X$ to elements of a set $Y$, $f^{-1}$ maps subsets of $Y$ to subsets of $X$.

The notation $f^*$ is used in the more abstract setting of *sheaf theory*, where it denotes the [*inverse image functor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_image_functor).  In that setting it means more or less the same thing, although its definition is more technical, as the link in the previous section suggests.  You didn't mention what the class you are taking is; if it is an algebraic geometry class, the professor may be using the notation $f^*$ because the more technical notion is coming up later.